# Can I establish a Remote Desktop connection to another user on the same computer?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-11, remote-connection

Is it possible to establish a Remote Desktop connection to a different user account on my own local PC?
I want to log in to my local PC as usual and then establish a Remote Desktop connection (127.0.0.1) to another user on the same computer. Is this achievable?

While I can remotely log in to my PC from a different device without any problem, I'm encountering an error when attempting to do this. Has anyone been able to do this before or is it simply not possible? Any guidance on this matter would be appreciated.

[image: Screenshot-02]

[image: Screenshot-01]

Comment: i believe this is possible with Server OSs, since more than one interactive session can exist concurrently, but with windows 7/8/10/11, in order to open the remote session, it would end the local session you are using to run the RDP client, which prevents you from actually interacting with the session.

Answer (score 3):

That is Windows Workstation (not Server).

You can have multiple users.

But you can only run one user at a time. Any attempt to run another user will log the first user out.

Using Switch User also has the same limitations.

That is how Windows has always worked: Single User at one time.

Comment: Windows multiseat has a long and complicated history. The short version is that Microsoft wants money. https://youtu.be/v8tjA8VyfvU?t=2968

Comment: Indeed, Win2k workstation allowed multi-session. by the time they got to XP though, they had locked down terminal services. I remember trying to hack it back in like 20 years ago, but was never successful.

Comment: @FrankThomas there was no need to "hack" your way like that, it was just a matter of replacing some files and it worked like a server

Comment: @ForeverSJC, perhaps your definition may differ, but frankenstein-ing an OS by overwriting it's components from another OS fits mine nicely.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to see a session by another user account, use the "Switch user"
option.

You may have multiple user sessions used in parallel, but only one
session can be active at any one time on Windows 11.

This is why you're getting the message
"Your computer could not connect to another console session on the remote computer because you already have a console session in progress",
because this would require having both your session and that of the
other user active at the same time.

For how to switch sessions, see the article
[6 Ways to Switch User Accounts in Windows 11](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-switch-user-accounts/).